# Statistics problem using SAS- How can I set my input which is given as a range?

Tags: statistics, sas, histogram

[image]

I want to use SAS code to solve this problem, but I don't know how to set my input since it is given as a range. Also, how can I use this range to make a histogram of the frequency distribution. Help please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can input it directly with `datalines` using a `|` as a delimiter (we're doing this because the salary range name has spaces in it). `sgplot` will plot the histogram, and the `freq=count` option will tell `sgplot` how many observations there are per range.

```
data have;
    length salary_range $16.;
    infile datalines dlm='|';
    input salary_range$ count;
    datalines;
25,000 to 29,999|12
30,000 to 34,999|23
35,000 to 39,999|37
40,000 to 44,999|19
45,000 to 49,999|15
50,000 to 54,999|9
;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    vbar salary_range / freq=count stat=percent;

    label salary_range = 'Salary Range';
run;
```

[image]

In practice, you'll have the raw data and want to use a `format` statement to create your bins. For example:

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 100;
        salary = rand('normal', 35000, 2000);

        if(salary < 25000) then salary = 25000;
        if(salary > 54999) then salary = 54999;
        output;
    end;

    drop i;
run;

proc format;
    value salaryRange
        25000 - 29999 = '25,000 to 29,999'
        30000 - 34999 = '30,000 to 34,999'
        35000 - 39999 = '35,000 to 39,999'
        40000 - 44999 = '40,000 to 44,999'
        45000 - 49999 = '45,000 to 49,999'
        50000 - 54999 = '50,000 to 54,999'
    ;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    histogram salary;

    label salary = 'Salary Range';
    format salary salaryRange.;
run;
```